# php echo certain id from database

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to echo dates 1 by 1 using the id field of the database, how do I call the first id using the code below?

I have a database named dbflagship, table called funds, rows are id date.

I want to use id and date to echo 1 date at a time.

Example: id 1 Date 10/11/2012

```
<?php echo $row['date_formatted']; ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "using the id field" and "the first id"?

Answer (score 0):

can you please print_r your result array here.

you can use this to print dates as per id.

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<count($row);$i++){ 
   echo $row[$i]['date_formatted'];
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

more info & source: http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_select.asp

www.w3schools.com is a great place to know

Answer (score 0):

Im im right you should try to fetch this in an mysql_fetch_assoc put it in an array. And after wards echo it by using an for loop.

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC");

for($i=0;$

echo $row[$i]['date_formatted'];
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "id:" . $row['id'];
  $timestamp = strtotime($row['date_formatted']))
  echo "Date".date('d/m/Y', $timestamp);

  }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```